# Swift - Unable to Create User in Firebase after Error Handling

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm able to create a new user in to firebase with the code below. However, once I introduced the duplicate username checking at the bottom, I'm running in to issues.

Scenario:
Create a new user with a unique address, but choose a username that exists already.

Flow:

- Insert unique email address
- Insert username that already exists in Firebase
- Execute the code below (via Create User button)
- Alert fires stating there's a username that already exists with that value
- Fix the username
- Execute the code again (via Create User button)
- This time I receive an error stating that my email address already exists, even though when I pull up the Firebase Console, the information has not written out yet.

Is there a way to refresh the `FIRAuth.auth()` prior to running it a second time? It's as if the previous "Create User" attempt is held in memory and tripping up the second execution.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password:pwd!, completion: {
(user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        switch(error!.code) {
        case FIRAuthErrorCode.ErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse.rawValue:
            self.showErrorAlert("Email Already Exists", msg: "This email address is currently in use.")
        default:
            self.showErrorAlert("Other Error", msg: "Please contact us with the following error code \(error?.code)")
        }
    } else {
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.queryOrderedByChild("Username").queryEqualToValue(userName).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
snapshot in 
        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
            print("The SnapShot Value: \(snapshot.value)")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user!.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
            let userData=["First Name": firstName!, "Last Name": lastName!, "Email": email!, "Username": userName!, "Age": age!, "Skill": skill!]
            DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(user!.uid, user: userData)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(NEW_USER_LOGGED_IN, sender: nil)
        } else {
            self.showErrorAlert("Username Already Exists", msg: "The username is currently in use. Please choose another.")
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this. I needed to check for the username existence first prior to executing the "createUserWithEmail" command. Once I shifted around the code to accommodate, it worked as expected.